# What is the best way to handle a casher payment mode

Tags: c#, enums, payment

Here is what I want to do :

We have a POS system based on a particular sub-system (let say SAP), but need to be able to switch to another (for instance MS Dynamics).

I want to create a new Payment Windows, where the user will be able to pay his invoice, with one **or many** payment mode (cash, debit, VISA...).

SO,  I though I would create an ENUM for the different PaymentMode that exist (..).  With that, it will be easy to switch from one sub-system (SAP) to another (Dynamics), because the enum should be the same :

```
Public enum PaymentMode
{
    AccountReceivable = 0,
    Cash = 1,
    Debit = 2,
    Check = 3,
    GiftCertificate = 4,
    Other_01 = 10, //depend on the sub-system...may be VISA/AMEX/MasterCard...
    Other_02 = 11, //depend on the sub-system...may be VISA/AMEX/MasterCard...
    Other_03 = 12, //depend on the sub-system...may be VISA/AMEX/MasterCard...
    Other_04 = 13  //depend on the sub-system...may be VISA/AMEX/MasterCard...
}
```

Also, I have a class that represent a real customer payment :

```
public class Payment
{
    public PaymentMode PaymentMode {get;set;} //here is my enum.  
    public double dbl_Amount {get; set;}
    public Datetime date_Payment {get; set;}
}
```

Then, having this, I find it clean and easy to add a payment to, let's say, an invoice :

```
   double dbl_TotalAmountToPay = 399,41;

   //can accept a multi-payment for a single invoice..
   List<Payment> myWholePayments = new List<Payment>();

   //FIRST PAYMENT
   Payment myFirstPayment  = new Payment; 
   myFirstPayment.PaymentMode = PaymentMode.Cash;
   myFirstPayment.dbl_Amount = 100;
   myWholePayments.add(myFirstPayment);

   //SECOND PAYMENT
   Payment mySecondPayment  = new Payment;
   mySecondPayment.PaymentMode = PaymentMode.Other_02; //based on the name shown on the button pressed (visa/AMEX...)
   mySecondPayment.dbl_Amount = 299.41;
   myWholePayments.add(mySecondPayment);
```

Then I can move my list of payment easily, even showing it in a Grid...

**Here is my questions (yes, finally) :**

1. Am I wrong to try the usage of an ENUM, based on the fact that it is not really static (like months).?
2. How can I manage to **DISPLAY** the name of the payment type, based on the fact that it may change from one system/customer (the credit card name are written by the manager of the SAP system).
   PaymentMode.Other_01 can be named "VISA" in one system, and "AMEX" in another.

   Same question apply to my Translator (convertir the ENUM to the end-system code).  In SAP, the "CASH" payment mode will be an integer of 0.  In Dynamics, it is a GUID {3131-3-b;ablabla}.  How can I translate that gracefully?

It's friday PM...so sorry if any stupidity in there... :|

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an enum should be "static" or at least not expected to change per implementation.

You should consider using the enum to handle general payment modes, and implement code to translate this meaning to the correct backend system.

```
Public enum PaymentMode
{
    AccountReceivable = 0,
    Cash = 1,
    Debit = 2,
    Check = 3,
    GiftCertificate = 4,
    AMEX = 5, 
    VISA = 6,
    etc
}
```

The translate code would be something like this, which you would invoke prior to calling the target system.

```
   public static object GetTranslatedValueForPaymentMode(PaymentMode pm)
    {
        if (backendSystem == "SAP)
        {    
            switch case (pm)
            {
                case PaymentMode.AMEX:
                    return "33"; //whatever code this is
                case PaymentMode.VISA:
                    return "AVC"; //whatever code this is
            }
        }
        else if (backendSystem == "GreatPains")
        {
            switch case (pm)
            {
                case PaymentMode.AMEX:
                    return new Guid("GKSKJDS"); //whatever code this is
                case PaymentMode.VISA:
                    return new Guid("DADADA"); //whatever code this is
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like that...The only thing is that I can't really know which custom payment mode (1,2,3,4) is VISA.  

Actually, I read the source system (SAP) for a list of "custom payments".  I then retrieve a code (from 5 to 9), and a description (written by the user : "visa","amex",...).

By writting my question, a light is blinking  : How can I "attach" a  Custom payment (PaymentMode.Custom_01) to the first occurence found in the source system...  Once tighted togheter, I will be able to "show" the "customer description" attachted with my PaymentMode.Custom_01

Comment: You will have to retrieve store the custom payments somewhere in your code. Then use the GetTranslatedValueForPaymentMode to read from that stored collection and return the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go for this approach:

```
public enum PaymentMode
{
    AccountReceivable = 0,
    Cash = 1,
    Debit = 2,
    Check = 3,
    GiftCertificate = 4,
    Visa = 5,
    Amex = 6,
    MasterCard = 7,
    Other = 20,
}
```

And then instead of simply mapping buttons 1, 2, 3, 4 to values `Other_01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, set up some code for each different key layout to map to the proper payment type. E.g.

```
public class Layout1 : LayoutBase
{
    public override PaymentMode GetPaymentType(int key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                return PaymentMode.Visa;
            // others...
        }
    }
}
public class Layout2 : LayoutBase
{
    public override PaymentMode GetPaymentType(int key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                return PaymentMode.MasterCard;
            // others...
        }
    }
}
```

And for the issue of `CASH` being represented by a GUID or a `0`, I'd say you could handle that with code as well:

```
public class DynamicsLayout : LayoutBase
{
    public override PaymentMode GetPaymentType(object raw)
    {
        if (raw is string && raw.ToString() == "{3131-3-b;ablabla}")
            return PaymentMode.Cash;
        // others
    }
}
```